# Fabry Perot interferometer

Tags: interferometry

I'm studying Fabry Perot Interferometer for the first time and I have some difficulties in understanding this model: there are two mirrors characterized by $r,t,T$ and between them there is a material with refractive index $n_r$. Outside the interferometer the index of refraction is $n_{out}$. Like in this picture:

[image]

What I don't understand are the mirrors because I don't know what they are.  For me they are just two slices of some material that can be characterized by the parameters $r,t,T$.
Furthermore, without them the beam would an analogous behavior since there is a separation surface between two media (as in the picture below)

[image]

I feel confuse, could you please give me some clarifications?

Comment: what are $t,r$ and $R$?

Comment: Your sentence beginning "What I don't understand..." seems to have some words missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I don't understand are the mirrors because I don't know what they are. For me they are just two slices of some material that can be characterized by the parameters r,t,T. Furthermore, without them the beam would an analogous behavior since there is a separation surface between two media (as in the picture below)

It's possible for the two mirrors to just be the interfaces between the two different materials.

They could also be the interfaces between the materials with multiple thin layers of different dielectrics in between, forming a [*high-reflective coating*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_coating#High-reflection_coatings). For that matter, you could also arrange the dielectric layers to form an *anti-reflective (AR) coating*, but this would degrade rather than enhance the performance of the FP interferometer. To understand the behavior of the FP interferometer it isn't necessary to understand how these coatings adjust the reflective properties of the material interface, but if you are studying the FP interferometer you will probably learn about coatings very soon.